# Persistence Layer Abstraction [Slick]

Tags: scala, playframework, architecture, slick, abstraction

I have a question about persistence layer abstraction.

### The goal

Create a structure not streactly Slick related, therefore *Entities*  must be disjointed from Slick and Slick-repo plug-in.

---

### Current situation

**Environment**

> - Scala % 2.12.4
> - com.typesafe.play % sbt-plugin % 2.6.12
> - com.typesafe.play % play-slick % 3.0.3
> - com.byteslounge % Slick-repo % 1.4.3

At the moment i have created abstraction with the following traits:

**IRepository:**

```
trait IRepository[E <: Entity[E, ID], ID] {

  type Transaction[T]

  val transactionManager: TransactionManager[Transaction]
  final type EntityType = E

  def findAll()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[Seq[E]]
  def findOne(id : ID)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[Option[E]]
  def lock(entity: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[E]
  def save(entity: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[E]
  def batchInsert(entities: Seq[E]): Transaction[Option[Int]]
  def update(entity: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[E]
  def delete(entity: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Transaction[E]
  def count(): Transaction[Int]
  def exclusiveLockStatement(sql: String): String
}
```

**TransactionManager:**

```
trait TransactionManager[T[_]] {

  final type Transaction[Entity] = T[Entity]

  implicit def executeAll[Entity](op: Seq[T[Entity]]): Future[Seq[Entity]]

  implicit def execute[Entity](op: T[Entity]): Future[Entity]
}
```

**Entity:**

```
trait Entity[T <: Entity[T, ID], ID] {

  final type IdType = ID

  val id: Option[ID]

  def withId(id: ID): T
}
```

In the services i'm using **implicit conversion** scala feature to execute *Db actions* and obtains **Future** instances

This is a simple example:

```
class UserServiceImpl @Inject()(private val repo: UserRepository)
                               (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends UserService {

  import repo.transactionManager._

  override def retrieve(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] =
    repo.findOne(id)

  override def save(user: User): Future[User] =
    repo.save(user)

  override def retrieve(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[User]] =
    repo.findByLoginInfo(loginInfo)

  override def delete(user: User): Future[User] =
    repo.delete(user)
}
```

---

### Problem

All these abstractions needs implementations and here the problems begin.

I think i have to give up on **repositories** abstraction because obliviously to use slick BDIO methods i need to have concrete access to that and this tie my code to Slick but i think it's ok.

Entities are not related to slick with my trait(Entity) but the troubles are on integration with repos.

My slick repos extends **Repository** class from **Slick-repo** plug-in, these class(like my IRepository trait) require two generic type, the first must extend a trait named Entity(Slick-repo's trait) while the second have no constraints and represent the id type of the entity.

**In summary:**

My classes

> - IRepository[**Entity**, ID]
> - Entity[**Entity**, ID]
> - SlickRepository[**Entity**, ID] extends IRepository

Slick-repo classes

> - Repository[*Entity*, ID]
> - Entity[*Entity*, ID]

SlickRepository extends/should use Repository(Slick-repo) but that class want that the first generic parameter exends Entity(Slick-repo) while in my case, for separation, it's extends Entity trait(my domain trait)

i hope it's clear, i know that the situation is a litle complex especially because some class have the same name

Maybe my concept of this problem is totally wrong i'don't know i hope someone can help me.

Thanks to all in advices.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Slick's Persistent Layer abstraction example here: https://github.com/gonmarques/slick-repo.

This repo provides common features like:

- Provide common database operations like save, update, find, delete or count in a type-safe way
- Other operations like Transactions, Batch Insert, Optimistic Locking (aka versioning),
- Pessimistic Locking or custom query/statement execution is also supported
- In order to maximize performance, all provided operations are backed by Slick compiled queries, as recommended in Slick Documentation